# Is there any callback that notifies once the app is updated to a new version in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to migrate my app after each version update. I am currently doing this while the app is launched after the update(i.e in application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)

If the user has turned on the Automatic updates for apps, app may remain in active state during and after the update. And so i cannot migrate the app immediately. is there any call back from application once the update is completed ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if the app is updated on the background, when the user relaunches it it will be from a fresh start (app delegate did launch with options). You could simply read the current version yourself and update accordingly every time you need.

Comment: "app may remain in active state during and after the update." - that is not feasible since basically the entire class and memory model of your application *might* change during an update. It may appear to the user as if the app was still active but it certainly wont just silently relaunch after an update.

Comment: @Pochi If the user relaunches the app after the app update, than no problem. But my problem is when the app stays foreground when it is simultaneously getting updated.

Comment: @luk2302  Are u saying the app will relaunch or won't relaunch?  I think it won't silently relaunch. Thats why i need to know whether there is any other callback that would notify the version change? Besides i cannot find any apple documentation regarding this.

Comment: *if* the app relaunches you will know about it, it *probably* does not happen silently. There is no other callback. Sadly docs are quite sparse on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the app update process.

The first thing you should understand is:

> An app CAN'T be updated while its running. It's impossible.

*talking about updates coming from the app store here

Theres just too many things that could go wrong if apps could be updated while running. So you can safely assume that:

> An app WILL ALWAYS start from a clean state after an update has
>   occurred.

This is why as long as you check if the app version has changed, you can always perform any migrations you might need.

This is in fact how the Core Data migration works. When an update has a different schema version an automatic migration is performed (if it has  properly been configured).

In fact, try opening the App Store app, select an available update for an app, press the update button, immediately try launching this app, if the app is currently being updated it will appear grayed out with a progress indicator. This is because:

> Apps won't run while they are being updated.